# Boot Menu Fedora and Window 7

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, boot-loader

I have install Fedora 20 before, a few days ago , I just install Window 7, and now I can not boot to Fedora because I don't have a boot menu. Is there anyway to recover the Fedora boot menu, is there any free software to do it without using the Fedora CD to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Windows before you install Fedora (or any other *NIX). Windows and its boot loader don't recognise *NIX installations. However, most *NIX setup programs will recognise a Windows installation.

Comment: I know Window dont recognise *nix, but current I have install Fedora first, dont you want me re-install both OS, I need solution to solve this issue.

Comment: That is the solution, because that's the way it's got to be done. Complain to Microsoft about that if it makes you feel better.

Comment: I didnt think re-install OS is smart solution, btw thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to boot with Fedora Live CD and reinstall the grub.
Nothing else is required.

Or at the max, for legacy grub. you may have to create /boot/grub/grub.conf file with one symlink /boot/grub/menu.lst, which will have entry for both OS.

`grub-mkconfig` command of grub2 will do this, if you are using grub2

Comment: thanks for your help. I knew this, just want to know there's a solution like a software on window 7 to do it, not need Fedora Live CD. Btw thank you, I will use Live CD for resolve this issue :).

Comment: From windows, Yes it is possible. You have to use `grub4dos` along with `grldr` and little modification in bootmgr